# How to append customized service into angular ng module directly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-module

I tried to add a custom service into the ng module directly

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module("ng")
    .service('getAQueryParameterByName', ['', function(){
        console.log("getAQueryParameterByName service active");
        this.getParameter = function(name){
            console.log("getParameter!");
        }
    }]);
```

As a result, when I try to run the service by doing `getAQueryParameterByName.getParameter(var)` I encountered error of

```
ReferenceError: getAQueryParameterByName is not defined
```

Usually this error is because I did not inject the service, however, I suppose, as I inject the custom service directly into the module, therefore, I really do not need to inject again into controller? But, I tried to add the service again into the controller anyway, and I received error of

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- getAQueryParameterByName
```

I am really confused at this point... Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your definition to:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module("ng")
    .service('getAQueryParameterByName', [function(){
        console.log("getAQueryParameterByName service active");
        this.getParameter = function(name){
            console.log("getParameter!");
        }
    }]);
```

Although, I wouldn't recommend extending the ng module.  That should be viewed as a third party as far as modular architecture.

Comment: so .... if I append additional services into another module, does all I need to is inject the custom module into the ng-app, without needed to inject any services that injected in the custom module, is that right?

Comment: That's correct all the components (services, providers, controllers, etc) are transitively included when you mark a module as a dependency.  For example if you have: angular.module('foo', [ 'bar' ]); module foo has access to all components in module bar and also to extend this case if module bar has dependencies you also have access to those modules as well.